# how to run env.render() in collab

Tags: google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, openai-api

---

NoSuchDisplayException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
      3 env.reset()
      4 for _ in range(1000):
----> 5     env.render()
      6     env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
      7 env.close()
```

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyglet/canvas/xlib.py in **init**(self, name, x_screen)

```
    121         self._display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(name)
    122         if not self._display:
--> 123             raise NoSuchDisplayException('Cannot connect to "%s"' % name)
    124 
    125         screen_count = xlib.XScreenCount(self._display)
```

NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to render in **Google Collab**
I use to debug and test code in my laptop and
I **train Model in Google Collab** .After it I **download that model** from **Google Colab** to my own pc. Finally using it to my projects

you can try this method